# About the syntax for catching two types of exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7

So this works:

```
try:
    raise OverflowError
except (IndexError, OverflowError):
    print 'caught'

caught
```

But this doesn't:

```
try:
    raise OverflowError
except IndexError, OverflowError:
    print 'caught'

OverflowError:
```

What does the second one do?

Comment: If you caught a `TypeError`, it would assign the instance to the name `OverflowError`; see e.g. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#rationale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `try` statement may have more than one except clause, to specify handlers for different exceptions. At most one handler will be executed. Handlers only handle exceptions that occur in the corresponding try clause, not in other handlers of the same try statement. An except clause may name multiple exceptions as a parenthesized tuple, for example:

```
except (IndexError, OverflowError):
    pass
```

Note that the parentheses around this tuple are required, because `except ValueError, e:` was the syntax used for what is normally written as `except IndexError as e:` in modern Python.

The old syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility. This means `except IndexError, OverflowError:` is not equivalent to `except (IndexError, OverflowError):` but to `except IndexError as OverflowError:` which is not what you want.